# Sparksql Int to date format

Tags: apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook

my table has a `date`  column that is the type `integer`

when I do:

```
sc.sql('select date from table).show(1)
```

I get:

```
19860102
```

but if I run:

```
sc.sql('select cast(date to Timestamp) from table).show(1)
```

I get:

```
1970-08-18 20:41:42
```

How can I convert this the df Date field from `Integer` to `string` to use `dayofweek` function?

Is there a way to do it using sql instead of  functions F?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with some string formatting and a bit of math.

```
select format_string('%d-%02d-%02d', floor(date / 10000), floor(date / 100) % 100, date % 100) from table
```

Comment: it didn't work.

Comment: @Katty_one in what way did this not work? also what version of spark are you using?

Comment: the column date is int.  The version is 2.4.4

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the error? This query assumes date is an int already. I updated the answer to return a string since I realized you were asking for a string rather than a date, but I don't think that solves the error.